# SQL - Finding entries that are the max of a count?

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, having

[image: Table]

I have a table like the above image shown, how can I display the id and names of the customers and the category of the food that have the customer ordered the most?

```
SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(F_Catg) 
FROM ORDER_RECORD ORD
INNER JOIN FOOD_MENU FM
ON ORD.Item_ID = FM.Item_ID
GROUP BY Customer_ID 
HAVING COUNT(F_Catg) = 
    (SELECT MAX(c) FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(F_Catg) AS c
         FROM ORDER_RECORD ORD
         INNER JOIN FOOD_MENU FM
         ON ORD.Item_ID = FM.Item_ID
         GROUP BY Customer_ID))
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a question. What is the problem specifically, any error? a wrong result? ..

Answer (score 0):

Your derived table is missing an alias.  Fix that, and your query should work:

```sql
SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(F_Catg)
FROM ORDER_RECORD ORD
INNER JOIN FOOD_MENU FM ON ORD.Item_ID = FM.Item_ID
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(F_Catg) = (SELECT MAX(c) FROM (
                            SELECT COUNT(F_Catg) AS c
                            FROM ORDER_RECORD ORD
                            INNER JOIN FOOD_MENU FM ON ORD.Item_ID = FM.Item_ID
                            GROUP BY Customer_ID) t  -- fix is here
                        );
```

On MySQL 8+, you could simplify a bit by using the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(F_Catg) AS cnt,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(F_Catg) DESC) rnk
    FROM ORDER_RECORD ORD
    INNER JOIN FOOD_MENU FM ON ORD.Item_ID = FM.Item_ID
    GROUP BY Customer_ID
)

SELECT Customer_ID, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```